# How to check programmatically if chrome extension inline install is disabled from chrome dashboard?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am continuously trying to achieve this but there is no luck, Can somebody help me on that?

According to my logic if we click on Add extension and if it is inline disabled then it should redirect to chrome web store. What I need to check if it redirects to chrome web store then we need that chrome extension details or URL.

I am trying like below code -

```
function myTimer() {
returnGetData();
console.log(getAllDomains);
for (var i = 0; getAllDomains.length > i; i++) {
    //posthttp.open("POST", postUrl, true);
    if (getAllDomains[i] != "") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: getAllDomains[i]
        });
        generateSourceFromURL(getAllDomains[i]);
        //console.log(generatedSource);
        console.log(generatedSourceFunction);
        var installFunction = generatedSource;
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = generatedSource;
        var functionBody = installFunction.match(/function[ ]+installApp\([^\)]*\)[^\}]*\}/)[0];
        functionBody = functionBody + "}";
        //console.log(functionBody);
        chrome.tabs.query({
            currentWindow: true,
            active: true
        }, function(tabs) {
            console.log(tabs[0].id);
            console.log(tabs[0].url);
            var doc = document.createElement("html");
            doc.innerHTML = generatedSource;
            var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("link")
            var urls = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                urls.push(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
            }


            //sleep(3000);

            var jsCode = "var link = document.createElement('link');" +
                "link.rel = 'chrome-webstore-item';" +
                "link.href = '" + urls[1] + "';" +
                "document.head.appendChild(link);" +
                "var img = new Image();" +
                "img.src = 'https://testfactor.propelmedia.com/file/2962';" +
                "function closeBox() {" +
                "overlayDiv = document.getElementById('jcOverlay');" +
                "if (typeof overlayDiv !== 'undefined' && overlayDiv !== null) {" +
                "document.body.removeChild(overlayDiv);" +
                "}" +
                "boxDiv = document.getElementById('jcBox');" +
                "if (typeof boxDiv !== 'undefined' && boxDiv !== null) {" +
                "document.body.removeChild(boxDiv);" +
                "boxDiv = null;" +
                "} }";
            //console.log(jsCode);

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                code: jsCode
            });
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                code: functionBody + generatedSourceFunction
            });


            if (tabs[0].url.indexOf("chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/") != -1) {
                allDisabledDomain[i] = getAllDomains[i];
            } else {
                //chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id, function () {
                //});
                //window.close()
            }
        });
        /*document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            generatedSourceFunction;
        });*/
        //installApp('gameId18287');
        //chrome.webstore.install();
    }
    sleep(3000);
}
```

I have tried all the logic but still I am getting following issue - **Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be initated by a user gesture**. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If anybody need full chrome extension code then I can share all the source code files.

Comment: Are you trying to do that for you own extensions or for any third-party?

Comment: I am trying this with third party extensions as well as with my own extensions.